# Testing Yesod handlers - examples

Tags: testing, yesod, persist

I've spent several hours trying to get a basic test framework going for testing Yesod handlers.  I'm still having some trouble.  It would be useful to look at a full working example, which includes interaction with the database.

Can someone direct me to any example(s) on the web? Ideally an open source yesod project, so I can see the scaffold in its entirety.  I've found several bits and pieces from different sources but so far they have not helped me all that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think they're particularly great test cases (there's alot of repetition and the database isn't wiped automatically between test cases), but you can take look at [these specs](https://github.com/MaxGabriel/hackvote-yesod/blob/master/test/Handler/HomeSpec.hs) I made for [this website](http://heyzaphackday.com/hackdays). The whole project's open source [on Github](https://github.com/MaxGabriel/hackvote-yesod).

Here's a sample:

```
homeSpecs :: Spec
homeSpecs =
    ydescribe "These are some example tests" $ do

        yit "loads the index and checks it looks right" $ do
            _ <- runDB $ rawExecute "TRUNCATE TABLE hack_day, project;" []
            get HackDayR
            statusIs 200
            htmlAnyContain "h2" "New Hackday"

        yit "shows the current hackday" $ do
            _ <- runDB $ rawExecute "TRUNCATE TABLE hack_day, project;" []
            currentTime <- liftIO $ getCurrentTime
            _ <- runDB $ insert $ HackDay { hackDayTitle = "testTitle"
                                          , hackDayCreated = currentTime
                                          , hackDayVotingClosed = False }
            get HackDayR
            htmlAllContain ".currentHackday" "testTitle"
```

Comment: Thanks.  My problem seems to lie elsewhere, as I can't see any differences between your setup and mine.  I'll leave this open for a day or two and then accept.

Comment: @unohoo is your project publicly available?